# Sending data to the html that is not connected with any view

Tags: python, html, django

How can I send a dictionary data to one of my html page that is not operated by any view in Django.
In this case, it's my `navbar.html`. I would like to insert few data about messages,  notifications etc.
How can i do that?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: If it is not operated by any view in django, how you are gonna even display that HTML page?

Comment: @bdemirka You are right.

Comment: @bdemirka This html is included in other, like {% include 'navbar.html' %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass additional data to an included template with [this syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

```
{% include "navbar.html" with myvar1="something" myvar2=othervariable %}
```

But of course all the data you want to pass into the included template must come from a view.